# How to find the equation of the conic before applying the rotation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, conic-sections, rotations

Given the rotation matrix:
$$Q=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}& \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\\-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}& \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\end{bmatrix},$$ I want to find the equation of the conic $C$ given by $$x^2+4xy+4y^2-10\sqrt{5}x=0,$$ which I know is a parabola, before applying the rotation to it.

I was thinking about solving the system of equation $$\begin{cases}x=\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\tilde{x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\tilde{y}\\ y=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\tilde{x}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\tilde{y}\end{cases},$$ and then substituting $x$ and $y$ in the initial equation of the conic. The result should be $$5\tilde{y}^2-20\tilde{x}-10\tilde{y}=0,$$ but it seems that my results are different.

Comment: You mean you want to find the equation *after* applying the rotation? Before applying it, you have the equation that you wrote down, or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I'm not sure but you may be applying the inverse rotation.

Comment: Another way, substantially equivalent but slighty easier in calculations, is to consider $(x,y)^tA(x,y)+B\cdot(x,y)$, and then applying  $(\tilde{x},\tilde{y})=Q(x,y)$

Comment: @Servaes No, the equation of the conic has been rotated by the rotation matrix. Now, I want to find the equation of the conic before the rotation.

Comment: @amd $-10\sqrt{5}x$

Comment: @gabrielecassese Ah, yes. Even simpler is to use homogeneous coordinates and consider $(M^{-1}\mathbf x)^TC(M^{-1}\mathbf x)=0$.

Comment: Please show us your result, to see if the mistake is due to a sign error.

Comment: Conic $C: x^2+4xy+4y^2-10\sqrt{5}x=0$ is hiperbola. Conic $5\tilde{y}^2-20\tilde{x}-10\tilde{y}=0$ is parabola.

Comment: @AleksasDomarkas Check your work. The original curve is indeed a parabola.

Comment: @amd Sorry, Conic $C: x^2+4xy+4y^2-10\sqrt{5}x=0$ is parabola with vertex [(1/10)*sqrt(5), 9*sqrt(5)*(1/20)].Conic $5\tilde{y}^2-20\tilde{x}-10\tilde{y}=0$ is parabola with vertex [-1/4, 1].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is entirely correct; plugging in your substitutions into the first equation for $C$ yields the result you claim it should be:
\begin{eqnarray*}
x^2+4xy+4y^2-10\sqrt{5}x&=&
\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\tilde{x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\tilde{y}\right)^2+4\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\tilde{x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\tilde{y}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\tilde{x}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\tilde{y}\right)\\
&\ &+4\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\tilde{x}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\tilde{y}\right)^2-10\sqrt{5}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\tilde{x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\tilde{y}\right)\\
&=&\frac{1}{5}(4\tilde{x}^2+4\tilde{x}\tilde{y}+\tilde{y}^2)+\frac{4}{5}(-2\tilde{x}^2+3\tilde{x}\tilde{y}+2\tilde{y}^2)\\
&\ &+\frac{4}{5}(\tilde{x}^2-4\tilde{x}\tilde{y}+4\tilde{y}^2)-10(2\tilde{x}+\tilde{y})\\
&=&5\tilde{y}^2-20\tilde{x}-10\tilde{y}.
\end{eqnarray*}
You seem to have made a mistake in your calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it looks like you’re getting the transformation backwards. If you have a coordinate transformation $\mathbf x'=Q\mathbf x$, to get the transformed equation you have to substitute for $\mathbf x$ in the original equation, i.e., apply the *inverse* transformation to $x$ and $y$ in the equation. So, if the original coordinate transformation was given by $Q$, you now want to transform by $Q^{-1}$, which means that you substitute $Q(x,y)^T$ for $(x,y)$ in the equation that you have.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have a conic with the equation $P(x,y) = 0.$
Next, you apply the rotation $Q$ to the conic,
so if $(\tilde x,\tilde y)$ is a point on the conic before rotation,
it is taken to the point 
$$
(x,y)=\left(\tfrac{2}{\sqrt5}\tilde{x}+\tfrac{1}{\sqrt5}\tilde{y},-\tfrac{1}{\sqrt5}\tilde{x}+\tfrac{2}{\sqrt5}\tilde{y}\right) \tag1
$$
after rotation.
Moreover, after applying the rotation, the rotated conic has the equation
$$ x^2+4xy+4y^2-10\sqrt{5}x=0. \tag2$$

If you now use Equation $(1)$ to provide the values of $x$ and $y$ 
in terms of $\tilde x$ and $\tilde y,$
you can make those substitutions for $x$ and $y$ in Equation $(2),$
and then you have an equation that must be satisfied by any point
$(\tilde x,\tilde y)$ on the original conic.

Try it.

The fact that one of your steps was to "solve" Equation $(1)$ suggests that your substitution was actually for a rotation by the correct angular magnitude, but in the opposite direction from what you needed.